# Why is inheritance not implicitly defined

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

This may have been answered before, but I couldn't find the words.

I'm trying to wrap my head around inheritance in `C++`, but coming from `C#` I can't seem to understand the reasoning behind the following case:

`Foo.h`

```
class Foo {
    virtual void DoSomething();
}

class Bar : Foo { }
```

`Bar.cpp`

```
#include "Foo.h"    
void Bar::DoSomething() 
{
    //Compiler error C2509 - member function not declared in 'Bar'
}
```

Since `DoSomething` is a <s>pure</s> virtual function, wouldn't it stand to reason that it would implicitly be declared as part of `Bar`?

If I have a lot of different classes inheriting from `Foo`, do I really need to explicitly declare `DoSomething` in each one of them?

What other constructs exist in `C++` to handle this case?

Comment: may I make a suggestion? For your own sanity, rename Bar.c to Bar.cpp

Comment: @KevinDTimm Sorry, fixed. That is of course not my actual file names.

Comment: As-written `DoSomething()` is not pure-virtual in `Foo`, `Bar`, or anywhere else. It is only virtual.

Comment: @WhozCraig Could you explain why not, and how it would be pure virtual?

Comment: `virtual void DoSomething() = 0;` would be a pure-virtual decl in the `class Foo` formal declaration.

Comment: Where do you tell the compiler that `Bar` shall not be abstract, too?

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, I see what you mean now. It does not affect the result in my case though.

Comment: @DyP I was assuming that's what implementing `Bar::DoSomething` would do.

Comment: @Rotem But users of the class who only see the header must know, too, if `Bar` is abstract or not.

Comment: @Rotem It doesn't. That is simply now how the language works. I could cite a raft of places in the standard that describe exactly how classes and their members are declared and implemented, and the requirements put-forth to be compliant with said-same standard, but ultimately it comes down to that.

Comment: @DyP I get it now. I guess I just didn't realize that an abstract class could have an inheritor which is also abstract, and that the compiler could not assume that `DoSomething` is implemented in an inheritor.

Comment: @Rotem: It doesn't even have to be abstract. A concrete sub class doesn't *have* to re-implement a (non-pure) virtual function, it'll just use the parent class's implementation if it doesn't, so the compiler can't make any assumptions about it. In any case, the inconvenience of having to declare it would appear be insignificant compared to the effort required to implement it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C++ language is built on the same principles of *independent translation* as C. This means that all translation units in C++ program should be compilable completely independently of each other. They are *linked* into the final *program* later, when the compiler proper has already finished working.

In case of classes, in order to be able to compile each translation unit independently the compiler must be able to build a sufficiently complete understanding of what the given class is by seeing the *definition* of the class alone, i.e. the part that is usually placed in header files. While compiling one translation unit, the compiler has to know that `DoSomething` is overriden in `Bar` and that the definition for `void Bar::DoSomething()` exists somewhere, in some other translation unit. In order to achieve that the class definition must include declarations for all class member functions.

Your reasoning about "pure virtual function" is completely unclear to me. Firstly, it is not pure in your code sample (apparently you simply forgot the `= 0` part). Secondly, just because the base class function is pure does not mean that the derived class function should be non-pure. It is quite possible that `Bar` was also supposed to be an abstract class. It is matter of your intent, which the compiler does not know.

Comment: Thanks. The false assumption in your last paragraph was the root of my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `Bar` is all most code is going to know about it. Other translation units will not see "Bar.cpp" but are still going to need to generate the correct in-memory representation of `Bar` instances, including `Bar`'s vtable. That means they need to know whether or not Bar is really overriding `Foo::DoSomething` or not, because the in-memory representation differs depending on that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need to explicitly declare this method. Coming from C#, you'll notice that C++ does not 'hold your hand' through a lot of things. I don't mean that insultingly, but C++ forces you to be incredibly explicit in everything you do.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear, you're saying that if you have an abstract `Foo` class as in my example, and you want 10 different specialized `Bar` classes, you would declare each one explicitly? I just assumed there would be an easier way.

Comment: Yes, you would have to explicitly state it in each of them.